# How to get comments into DDLs

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

My data model has all the table comments and column comments in the `Comments` section rather than `Comments in RDBMS`. This way whenever I generate the DDL's from the data model the comments are literally printed next to the columns rather than being printed as `COMMENT ON TABLE` or `COMMENT ON COLUMN` which is working as expected.

Is there any way to move these comments into the RDBMS comments so that they appear on the DDL's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a hack around this.

1. Go to search option and extract all the COMMENTS field on that schema into excel
2. Using formula option build dynamic SQL string for those column comments
3. Store them